# .Net ORM/Business Object Framework Performance

Tags: c#, .net, orm, oop, frameworks

Currently I am working with a custom business object layer (adopting the facade pattern) in which the object's properties are loaded from stored procedures as well as provide a place for business logic.  This has been working well in the attempt to move our code base to a more tiered and standardized application model but feel that this approach is more of an evolutionary step rather than a permanent one.

I am currently looking into moving to a more formal framework so that certain architecture decisions won't have to be my own.  In the past I have worked with CSLA and Linq to SQL and while I like a lot of the design decisions in CLSA I find it a bit bloated for my tastes and that Linq to SQL might not have the performance I want.  I have been interested in the popularity of NHibernate and the push of Linq to Entity however performance is a key issue since there are instances where a large number of records need to be fetched at a time (> 15k) (please do not debate the reason for this) and am curious as far as performance what looks like the best choice for adopting a formal .Net Object Framwork?

**NOTE:** This will be used primarily in Winform and WPF applications.

**Duplicate:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146087/best-performing-orm-for-net

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about Object-Relational Mapping Frameworks (ORMs for short) - you should consider changing the title of your question to specify that since many people may not undertand what you mean by 'Object Framework'.

Comment: I think you're looking for an Object-Relational Mapper (ORM), not a ".Net object framework". You may want to change the title accordingly...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I changed it to ORM/Business Object Framework as I'm not opposed to a something similar to CSLA which is not quite an ORM.

Comment: And now it's just a matter of finding people who actually want to talk about performance. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://ormbattle.net - the performance test there seems almost exactly what you want to see.

You must look at materialization test (performance of fetching large number of items is exactly what it shows); moreover, you can compare ORM performance with performance of nearly ideal SQL on plain ADO.NET doing the same.

Comment: That is great!  More data than I was even looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With any ORM you're going to get a boost out of the box via a Level 1 in proc cache.  Especially with loads, if it's already there it won't take a trip to Pluto(the DB).  Most ORMs have the opportunity to inject a L2 out proc cache.  The nice thing about these is that they just plug into the ORM.  Checkout NCache for NHibernate.

Comment: If cache usage is _possible_, there can be a boost. But e.g. if he reads thousands of pretty simple objects sequentially from the database, cache won't help much: caches in ORM significantly increase the performance on random reads (in fact, by simply reducing the chattiness between ORM & RDBMS), but not on sequential reads (since there is no chattiness at all).

Answer (score 1):

O/R mapper performance will depend greatly on how your application is designed and how you map the business objects. For example, you could easily kill performance by lazy loading a child object in a loop so that 1 select for 1000 objects turns into 1001 selects (google n+1 select).

One of the biggest performance gains with o/r mappers is in developer productivity, which is often more important than application performance. Application performance is usually acceptable to end users for most applications running on recent hardware. Developer performance continues to be a bottleneck, no matter how much Mountain Dew is applied to the problem. :-)